# Рекурсивная функция. Рекурсивные алгоритмы

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Изучаем в вузе Рекурсивные функции, к преподавателю в данный момент нет возможности подойти. Подскажите как реализовать. Определить принадлежит ли заданный элемент одномерному
массиву
Для решения задачи описать рекурсивную функцию. Так начал:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

int prm(int p1, int p2, int m[], int p3, int p4)
{
    for (p2 = 0; p2 <= p1; p2++)
    {
        if (m[p2] = p3)
        {
            p4 = 1;
        }
        else p4 = 2;
    }
    if (p4 = 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int z = prm(5, 0, { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Создать функцию. Задать в аргументах размер, индекс, искомый элемент, массив. 1. Описать условие - поиск невозможен. 2. Проверить по индексу элемент, если совпал - вернуть ответ. 3. Вызывать функцию повторно, увеличив индекс.

Comment: == нужно писать

Comment: Вместо for - нужно делать вызов (с наращиванием индекса). Можно до, можно после "тела цикла" (точнее "тела функции").

Comment: @Антон Александрович теперь у вас есть возможность поставить нам стрелочки вверх)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет такого варианта?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


bool prm(int elem, int* arr, int size)
{
    static int cnt = 0;
    static int not_match = 0;

    if (not_match > size) return false;
   
    if (elem == arr[cnt++])
        return true;
    else
        ++not_match;
        return prm(elem, arr, size);
   
}



int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 2,3,4,5,0 };
    bool ok = prm(3, arr, 5);
    cout << std::boolalpha << ok << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

`std::boolalpha` - для вывода `true/false` вместо `1/0`

Желаете прямо вставить безымянный массив в функцию?

```
using arr = const int[5];
bool prm(int elem, arr const& array, int size)    
...
bool ok = prm(45, { 2,3,4,5,0 }, 5);
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение.

Comment: благодарю, удачи в изучении

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных - плохо. Обычно **не принято** использовать глобалыне переменные в таких случаях. Так же... тогда возникают вопросы, а почему только `p` и `cnt`? Можно `size` и `elem`, и даже `arr` вынести тогда в глобальную область, не жертвуя функциональностью. Очень много зацепок что бы препод смог пригрузить.

Comment: Я Вас понял, исправил

Comment: Так ещё лучше, препод скажет а мы не проходили `static`, расскажите что это))) И бедный студент... ну может сочинит чего)))

Comment: Голосовавшие против приглашаются объяснить что не так?

Comment: Я минусов не ставил, но функция нечитабельна

Answer (score 4):

```
bool is_in(int x, int a[], int first, int last)
{
    if (a[first] == x) return true;
    if (first == last) return false;
    return is_in(x,a,first+1,last) ;
}

...

int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
cout << is_in(5,a,0,6);
```

Так устроит?

Или еще короче - с конца:

```
bool is_in(int x, int a[], int n)
{
    return (n == 0) ? false : a[n-1] == x ? true : is_in(x,a,n-1);
}
...

int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
cout << is_in(5,a,7);
```

Для особо желающих писать массив прямо в вызове (а что, сразу не видно, входит или нет? :))

```
bool is_in(int x, initializer_list<int> a, int n = -1)
{
    if (n == -1) n = a.size();
    return (n == 0) ? false : data(a)[n-1] == x ? true : is_in(x,a,n-1);
}

....

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << is_in(5,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
}
```

Передавать при этом что-то еще, кроме массива и значения, не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо. Что происходит когда на месте аргумента массива указываем a? Здесь cout << is_in(5,a,0,6);

Comment: напрямую писать is_in(5,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},0,6) нельзя, ругается компилятор на попытку передать указатель на временный объект. Тобто массив {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} существует пока выполняется эта строка, но что будет делать функция с полученным указателем неизвестно, например сохранит в глобальной переменной... но массив существует лишь до конца выполнения строки, и глобальные данные станут ошибочными. Таким образом компилятор просто ругается.

Comment: Что происходит? Передается указатель на массив. Если кто-то хочет передавать именно `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` - то тут уже надо использовать `initializer_list`, а не массив  (`{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` - **не** массив!) - см. обновленный ответ...

Comment: `initializer_list` - требует **include** и **весию** с++ там с++11 или какую-то... лучше указать. Конечно через `template <int size> bool is_in(int x, int & a[size], int n = -1) ` будет при любой версии работать, но думаю template - уже продвинутый уровень)))

Comment: @nick_n_a По-моему, `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` передать в этом шаблонном варианте не получится...

Comment: Да, прийдется через переменную, через template аргумент  константой в с++ старом нельзя

Comment: @nick_n_a Я вас так понял, что вы предлагали шаблоном именно `initializer_list` заменить.

Comment: далеко вы закатили. Студент наверно не поймет)

Comment: Тут есть нормальный вариант (первый) и вариант для "продвинутых", так что поймёт.